# How can I use source with variables?

Tags: bash

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work, but no go:  I just want to use $path in my source command.

```
#!/bin/bash

path="~/root/config/bash/"

source ~/root/config/bash/_private.sh
source ~/root/config/bash/config.sh
```

Comment: What about `source $path`? Although it is not very clear to me what you wish to achieve...

Comment: Be careful about using `$path`. The lower case version is reserved in tcsh which might (albeit inadvisedly) be used in scripts on your system. Better safe than sorry, and use variables that won't conflict with anything.

Comment: Oh, and for use in variables, consider using `$HOME` instead of `~`, since the tilde may be treated literally instead of being expanded.

Comment: You don't need to cater to `tcsh` in a shell script any more than you would Python, Perl, or other interpreted language. It's a separate interpreter, and one that any sanely configured system is *not* using as the default shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash parameters are expanded by the shell, before the command sees them as arguments.

`source "$path"` is all you need.

*Unless* you're talking about using it as a prefix, in which case, you could do:

`source "${path}/_private.sh"`, etc.

However, if you're talking about using $path as if it were $PATH, and let it look for files there if they can't be found elsewhere, that would require custom logic.

Answer (score 3):

Tilde (`~`) will be treated literally in a path when put inside quotes, in a variable declaration, so `source $path` won't work.

You can:

- Use `eval` (be careful):

  ```
  source "$(eval echo $path)"
  ```
- Or use alphabetic full path:

  ```
  path=/home/user/root/config/bash/
  ```
- Or if the user is same as the login user, use `$HOME`:

  ```
  path="$HOME"/root/config/bash/
  ```
- Or keep `~` [outside of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36801438/3789550)

Comment: Tilde expansion works for variable assignments as long as it is unquoted and at the beginning of the value (or immediately after a colon, to accommodate lists of directories for variables like `PATH`). No need to even mention `eval`.

Comment: For `$USER`, you mean `$HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

```
path=~/"root/config/bash/"
source "$path"
```